# Kafka CLI in DC/OS Mesosphere

Tags: command-line-interface, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, mesosphere, dcos

I have very recently started playing around with DC/OS Mesosphere. I installed Kafka as a service on my cluster. I had a very simple question:

To list topics, can I still use this command: 

`kafka-topics --zookeeper zookeeper-host:2181 --list`

or would I have to use the dcos command:

`dcos kafka --name=kafka topic list`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be able to run `kafka-topics` directly if you like, but you'd want to provide a zookeeper path which matches the name of the Kafka service instance (default `kafka`).

You can get this path by running `dcos kafka --name=kafka connection` and looking at the `zookeeper` entry in the returned data:

```
$ dcos kafka --name=kafka connection
{
  "address": [
    "10.0.0.58:9603",
    "10.0.0.56:9805",
    "10.0.0.55:9556"
  ],
  "zookeeper": "master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka",
  "dns": [
    "broker-0.kafka.mesos:9603",
    "broker-1.kafka.mesos:9805",
    "broker-2.kafka.mesos:9556"
  ],
  "vip": "broker.kafka.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:9092"
}
```

In this example the `--zookeeper` value passed to `kafka-topics` should be `master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka`. This assumes that the `master.mesos` host is reachable from wherever you're running the `kafka-topics` command.